# Motor Current Limiting Algorithm

Tags: pic, h-bridge, pid-controller, current-limiting

I am building a H-Bridge controller dor DC motors, and I want to add some current limiting on it. Does anyone knows a good algorithm for doing so?
I am planning to read the current, and if it goes beyond a limit, I start a PI loop until it drops under the limit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you just want current limiting and don't need motor short-circuit protection, you could implement cycle-by-cycle current limiting (also called [hiccup-mode](http://sva.ti.com/assets/en/appnotes/national_power_designer125.pdf) current limiting).

Instead of trying to do full loop closure on the current, simply use a comparator to turn the H-bridge off as soon as the instantaneous current crosses a pre-set threshold.  It can be implemented as a comparator in either hardware or (fast) firmware.  The H-bridge stays off for the rest of the cycle, but is allowed to turn on with the next cycle.  Note that this approach requires an inductive load to work effectively.

Comment: Thank's I am going to read it...but it sounds simple...

Comment: Ah.. that link to the article on TI is broken; returns 404

Answer (score 0):

Microchip has an application note on PID algorithms available [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en020434). I would start there.

Comment: I already have some material about PID...but PID is a problem, because it stabilizes the current, I just want to bring it down...